# How to check that which storage connected either FC or iscsi

Tags: linux, storage, iscsi, fc

How do i check that, which type of storage are connected with my linux(Redhat) system. I want to find that either ISCSI or FC storage connect ?

Comment: Do you have `iscsiadm`? `lscpi`?  What linux distribution?  What sort of storage system are you running?

Comment: linux distribution is redhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `lsscsi -t`. For FC devices, the 3rd column will say `fc:<port name>,<port id>`. For iSCSI devices, it should display the iSCSI target name (e.g. `iqn.2001-04.com.example:sda.sdb.sdc`), although this could vary depending on whether you're using a hardware or software implementation of iSCSI.

For example, this is a FibreChannel LUN:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    fc:0x500507680c258479,0x0b0801  /dev/sdb
```

And this would be an iSCSI LUN:

```
[2:0:0:0]    disk    iqn.2001-04.com.example:sda.sdb.sdc,t,0x1 /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 1):

for FC try

```
systool -c fc_host -v
```

which give a report for all FC card, and a more details for connected one.

You are seen by SAN with the wwid given by `port_name`

if no FC present (*)

```
Error opening class fc_host
```

(*) note that not present and unconnected are different thing.